# Clustered Index Update Slow Update On Large Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a problem updating a large table with millions of rows please advice to reduce the update time.

Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_sms_job_detail](
    [JobDetailID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [JobID] [int] NULL,
    [DistributorID] [int] NULL,
    [ResellerID] [int] NULL,
    [CustomerID] [int] NULL,
    [SenderID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [SMSMessage] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [MessageType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MessageLength] [int] NULL,
    [MessageParts] [int] NULL,
    [ClientRate] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [ClientCost] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [ResellerRate] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [ResellerCost] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [DistributorRate] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [DistributorCost] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [RouteDetailID] [int] NULL,
    [SMSID] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [DLRStatus] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ErrorCode] [int] NULL,
    [ErrorDescription] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
    [SentDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [SentDateUTC] [datetime] NULL,
    [SMSSource] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SMSType] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [APISMSID] [int] NULL,
    [DLRDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [DLRDateUTC] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_sms_job_detail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [JobDetailID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20170919-173756] ON [dbo].[tbl_sms_job_detail] (   [JobID] ASC,    [DLRStatus] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20170919-174142] ON [dbo].[tbl_sms_job_detail]
(
    [SMSID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

Update Procedure

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[sp_update_message_status]
@SMSID nvarchar(200),
@DLRStatus nvarchar(100),
@ErrorCode int,
@ErrorDescription nvarchar(2000)
AS
UPDATE tbl_sms_job_detail SET DLRStatus = @DLRStatus, ErrorCode = @ErrorCode, ErrorDescription = @ErrorDescription WHERE SMSID = @SMSID
```

Execution Plan

[image: Execution Plan Image]

This Procedure is called up to 1000 times in several minutes and some of them fail to update as it takes time to update the previous record what can be done to increase the update of a record in this table.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the issue is not being caused by the actual clustered index but by the effect the update query has.

MSSQL is a page based storage system. When adding records to the table, as the clustered index is on the field [JobDetailID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, each new record is applied to the last page currently at the table (if it will fit) or a new page is tacked onto the end of the table and the record stored in it.

Assuming that [DLRStatus] and/or [ErrorDescription] start of a null or empty strings, when the update sproc runs, it has to find some space in the page that the record is already in to store the new value in. SQL keeps a little space in each page file for such purpose, but when that space is used up, it will have to do a page split - splitting the contents of the one page file into the existing page file and a newly created blank page file. As the primary key is clustered, this new page file has to be inserted so it keeps the records stored in the table in the clustered index order. It is quite likely that this page splitting is at the root of the problem.

The amount of space that SQL keeps back before creating a new page is configurable, therefore one solution is to initially create the page files with plenty of 'expansion' room. On an index it is called the fill factor, but I am not sure what the correct term is for data pages (probably still a fill factor, but not sure).

Another alternative is to store the returned error information in a separate table and then store the primary key for the 'error information' record in table [tbl_sms_job_detail]. As long as the key is not a nvarchar / varchar (and who would do this anyway), the space required in the page file will already be reserved. Thus recording the error information requires appending the variable text information to the end of the last page file for the new table and updating a foreign key in your original table that already has space reserved for it and so doesn't trigger of a page slit.

Comment: What if the key was a char? I'm seeing 4 seconds to update an int field with a single field nchar index on one of our tables.